# How to write "if" condition for resultText.text?

Tags: iphone, if-statement, conditional-statements

The following is code from the Zbar SDK, which allows you to scan barcodes. Once a barcode is read, the barcode number appears in a textView box on the interface. Where you see resultText.text = symbol.data is where the barcode decodes the info and allows the barcode to appear in the textView box. So basically since whatever the barcode decodes is placed in resultText.text, I added the "if" condition :

```
if ([symbol.data = 04176400]) {
    resultText.text = @"This is a sprite bottle";
}
```

The barcode on the sprite bottle is 04176400. So I wanted the text "this is a sprite bottle" to show up instead of 04176400, which is the barcode on the bottle. However, this "if" condition above does not work. Xcode displays the error "assignment to readonly property". I believe my "if" condition is faulty in entirety although it appears logical.And what should I place instead of this, I'm quite clueless. Below is the code that processes the barcode data in totality.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;
    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;

    //THIS IS THE FAULTY CODE.
    if ([symbol.data = 04176400]) {
        resultText.text = @"This is a sprite bottle";
    }


    // setup our custom overlay view for the came
    // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    //Delete below in entirety for continuous scanning.
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare the two values.

`if ([symbol.data == 04176400])`

In Objective-C, `==` is a comparative operator, and what you should be using in this situation. `=` is typically used for assignment. And on a separate note, you would get the same error if you tried to properly alter `symbol.data` because Xcode is saying it is a read-only property that cannot be altered.

Comment: This is true, unless he wants to compare strings (which he might, not sure how his barcodes are coming in) he should use isEqualToString.

Comment: True, or `if ([symbol.data == @"04176400"])` would work as well.

Comment: No, that doesn't work because it compares the pointers, which could be different. Always use isEqualToString for strings.

Comment: You guys are correct, the entire logic I was using is faulty. I've looked up the isEqual method but I'm confused between isEqualToString, isEqual, isEqualTo.  How would I implement the isEqualToString in this case?

Comment: If symbol.data is an NSString, then use isEqualToString. In general, when comparing objects use a variation of isEqual (the docs will tell you what to do, always read the docs) and if it is not an object (i.e., float, integer, etc) then use ==.

Comment: Yes, symbol.data is an NSString. So you're saying I should replace == with isEqualToString in such cases, and if that doesn't work, the rule of thumb is that isEqual something method will work? Let us assume this fails(not on Mac atm to test), what other alternatives would I have? Thanks so much for being responsive btw!

Comment: if ([symbol.data isEqualToString: @"04176400"]]) {
..
}

isEqual should be used if you're comparing two objects of any kind,
isEqualToString is especially for strings

Comment: It'd be polite to mark the answer as correct if it helped you.